# Constraint on return and error to make sure one is defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a simple case, hook function that returns `{data, error}` For simplicity lets assume that both are strings. While both error and data can be `undefined` when the second is returned, It's not possible that both are undefined together.

Do I have a way in typescript to set constraint that it will never happen that both are undefined? I use function in the React component and I would like this code

```
const myComponent: React.FC= function(){
 const { data, error } = useMyCustomHook(); 

 if ( error ) return<div> error </div>
 if (data) return <div> data </div>

}
```

to be ok. Instead it throws

`Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.`

Which wouldnt be here if there would be a way to tell typescript that `error || data` is always true.

One solution would be to make two interfaces one that require `error` with optional `data`another that require `data` leaving `error` optional and then type `useMyCustomHook` return to be union of those two, but it sounds like a bad solution that doesnt work in the scale. Imagin what will happen if I would like to have one property out of five, or even two out of five to be defined.

Comment: You can define two differened return types for your function: { data: string, error?: unknown } | { data: undefined, error: string } so that the compiler knowns that if data is undefined error is not. Maybe you give it a try.

Comment: @ThomasRenger yeah I mentioned this solution at the end of my question. But as I mentioned there it looks a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see what type `useMyCustomHook` returns.

If data can be falsy, such as `undefined`, the current code will miss one condition. In this case, you should handle the case where data is falsy.

You can modify the code like this:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { data, error } = useMyCustomHook(); 

  if (error) return <div>error</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>empty</div>;

  // you can safely access to the data
  return <div>data</div>;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular function as a component, so as not to be restricted to the `React.FC type`. This should still be a valid component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, error } = useMyCustomHook(); 

  if (error) return <div>error</div>;
  if (data) return <div>data</div>;
}
```